# Conseguir 2 datos de dos tablas diferentes

Tags: sql

Quiero conseguir todos los emails de una tabla de `usuarios`, y el solo un email de la tabla de `empresa`.

Tengo este para conseguir los emails de una tabla, pero cómo puedo añadir otro `SELECT` para que me salgan juntos? y poder luego utilizar estos datos. Había pensado algo así, pero no estoy seguro de que lo este haciendo bien

```
SELECT usuario.email FROM usuario 
WHERE usuario.tipo_usuario='usuario' AND usuario.bolsa_ofertas='activado' 
(SELECT empresa.email FROM empresa WHERE empresa='ejemplo');
```

Comment: y como son las tablas? o querias unir los querys?

Comment: son dos tablas que no tienen relación entre ellas.   He probado SELECT email FROM usuario INNER JOIN ofertas_empleo ON ofertas_empleo.email_empresa = 'darwin@gmail.es'
 Y me da el resultado que busco, pero el problema es que también necesito añadir el WHERE, y no me deja

Comment: ¿Puedes anexar la estructura de ambas tablas?

Comment: Si no hay relacion entre ellas, cual es el resultado que estas esperando obtener? podes mostrarlo?

Comment: Para ayudarte a encontrar la forma de relacionar los datos, me uno a la recomendación de mostrar la estructura de las tablas y algunos datos de prueba para entender cómo son tus datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si te sea útil la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT usuario.email, empresa.email FROM usuario 
    JOIN empresa 
    WHERE usuario.tipo_usuario = 'usuario' 
    AND empresa.empresa = 'ejemplo' 
    AND usuario.bolsa_ofertas = 'activado'
```

Answer (score 0):

como no se los campos relacionado de las tablas usuario y empresa te paso un ejemplo de como podria ser si es que te sirve:

SELECT u.usuario.email, e.empresa.email from usuario u, empresa e where e.cod.empresa=u.cod.usuario